# Unzip libwebsockets-1.22-chrome26-firefox18.tar.gz

Tags: mqtt

I am trying to install libwebsockets into my RPi.

I used the `wget http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/snapshot/libwebsockets-1.3-chrome37-firefox30.tar.gz`
to download the file.

but when I try to unzip it I get the error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have tried

```
tar -xvzf libwebsockets-1.22-chrome26-firefox18.tar.gz
```

and

```
tar xf libwebsockets-1.22-chrome26-firefox18.tar.gz
```

I have tried to unzip separeted:

```
gunzip libwebsockets-1.22-chrome26-firefox18.tar.gz 
tar xf libwebsockets-1.22-chrome26-firefox18.tar
```

What would be my option to have that file and keep my installation?

The tutorial I am following: http://goochgooch.co.uk/2014/08/01/building-mosquitto-1-4/

Comment: Have you checked the actual file type? It could just be an html file with an error message. Try the `file` command with the .gz filename as the parameter

Comment: It showed libwebsockets-1.22-chrome26-firefox18.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text. What should I do?

Comment: As I said: it may contain an error msg. Open the file in a text editor and see what it says. Next action depends on what's in the file. BTW: that tutorial is quite old and I don't think it was recently updated, so links, etc may be invalid by now. If I open the link to the file I don't get a file download. And are you trying to build an old version of mosquitto? AFAIK current versions support web sockets already.

Comment: that url redirects to `https://warmcat.com/git/` a web page .. `wget` even tells you that

Comment: You are right Dirk, current versions support web sockets already.